# Update (model.save()) in Mongo DB / Sails JS is functioning only once

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

this is my code snippet

```
Punch.findOne({Employee: id, Date: thisDate}).exec(function (err,model) {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);                   
            }
            else
            {   var date = new Date();
                var thisTime =  date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds().toString();             
                model.Out=thisTime;
                model.save(function(err){

                    if (err) {

                        req.session.pStatus="failed";               
                        res.view('Person/punch/');

                    }else {
                        Person.findOne(id).exec(function(err,emp) {
                        emp.Punched='No';
                        emp.save(function(err){ console.log(err)});
                        req.session.punch=emp.Punched;
                        req.session.pStatus="Punched Out at "+thisTime;
                        res.render( 'Person/punch',{'model':emp});
                    });

                    }


                  });
            }       
        });
```

here the `model.save()` is functioning only one time by updating the time value. In later function calls it doesn't update the generated time value

Comment: Its not clear what 'later function calls' you mean.  You need to provide a better example.